# How do I make this counter count for a specific list item in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to make a counter that count everything specific in the list, but now when i press the + or - they all change to the same number. What should i change to make it work, I am very new to flutter and any help would be greatly appriciated. Going further I would like to use the numbers from each item in list, in a datebase. Any tips for that would also be greatly appriciated.

```
import 'package:discmania200/AddPlayerScreen.dart';
import 'package:discmania200/PlayerAddNotifier.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

final String title = 'home';
var _itemCount = 1;

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  fullscreenDialog: true,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AddPlayerScreen();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Consumer<AddPlayerNotifier>(
              builder: (context, addPlayerNotifier, _) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: addPlayerNotifier.playerList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(                           
                            title: Text(
                              addPlayerNotifier.playerList[index].playerName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            trailing: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                _itemCount != 0
                                    ? IconButton(
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                                        onPressed: () => setState(
                                              () => _itemCount--,
                                            ))
                                    : Container(),
                                Text(_itemCount.toString()),
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                  onPressed: () => setState(
                                    () => _itemCount++,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: move `title` and `_itemCount` inside `_HomeScreenState`

Comment: @Chiller i did that now, but same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a counter that is specific to a list item, you should not be leaving `_itemCount` in `_HomeScreenState`, you should be storing and mutating that value in your Player class (I am not the sure of the name of your Player class, but it's whatever the type of the members of `addPlayerNotifier.playerList` are). Your goal seems to be to have this itemCount number be an attribute of a player just like `playerName` is an attribute of a player.

I am not sure the exact type of `AddPlayerNotifier` but I recommend a `ChangeNotifier` for your use case. I recommend adding a new method to `AddPlayerNotifier` that looks something like this:

```
void updatePlayerItemCount(int index, int count) {
  playerList[index].itemCount = count;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

To explain this a bit, the first line just updates the count for the player by accessing it via the `playerList` and updating it to match `count`. Then it calls the `notifyListeners()` function, part of `ChangeNotifier` which alerts its consumers (such as `_HomePageState`) to re-build. This will display your new count to the user.

In `_HomePageState` all you will need to do to accommodate this change is to change the `onPressed` attributes of your buttons to be something like this (this example is for the increment button):

```
onPressed: () {
  addPlayerNotifier.updatePlayerItemCount(
    index,
    addPlayerNotifier[index].itemCount + 1,
  );
}
```